# Terraform Development local - visual studio code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, terraform

I am using visual studio code for terraform development and handling the deployment through Azure Devops. During deployment I am using replace tokens task to replace gitUser and gitAccessToken (Personal access token) values, which works without any issues. But, I can't find a way during development in my local PC. Currently, I am masking the current source line and adding a new line with original values. Is there an alternate way of doing this?

```
module "az-resource-group" {
  source              = "git::https://#{gitUser}#:#{gitAccessToken}#@github.com/myorg/Module-RG"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  tags                = var.tags
}
```

Comment: Can you use a module registry instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [the doc](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/sensitive-variables) to protect sensitive input variables in Terraform. Hope this similar ticket [How to pass Variables to Terraform modules via CLI or tfvars file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878553/how-to-pass-variables-to-terraform-modules-via-cli-or-tfvars-file) would help you.

Comment: Hi Dilly, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If my reply helped or gave a right direction, appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) which will also help others in the community.